# $_SERVER vartiables are dropped on my hosting running CGI

Tags: php, cgi

The variables $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] are returned as empty because of the setup my hosting has (Running on a CGI interface). Is there any work around to get them to work as I need to use them for auth. I can't move hosting or change the interface.

I am sending auth requests via curl to a url /api/projects/...
which is interpreted by a modrewrite and then processed according to the rules.

When I try this on my local host running MAMP, or I use my other hosting it works ok (not using CGI interface) but on the server I need it to run on, the variables are dropped!

Can some one help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the manual, those variables are only available when PHP runs as an Apache module. http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

You can try talking to your hosting provider and see if they can make them available to you when CGI dispatches the request.

Comment: I should have checked that. Unfortunatly they can;t make them available to me. Do you know if it is possible to use a work around similar to here: http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/04/http-authentication-on-php-as-cgi-like-dreamhost/

Comment: It really depends which environment variables are made available to you. A starting point might be `print_r($_SERVER)` and check what CGI is making available to you.

Comment: By adding:
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

I have made the PHP_AUTH_PW & PHP_AUTH_USER available to me and that seems ok. Half way there now! Just need internal server rrequests to work!

Comment: Internal requests could be handled using REMOTE_ADDR? If REMOTE_ADDR is the ip address of the server you are running on, then you can assume it's an internal request. This does pose a security issue, as someone on the same server as you could make requests that look internal.

Comment: Ah ok I will have a look into this. Does that mean I can use curl in a script in one dir to use the api in another dir. Where would the REMOTE_ADDR be used? Sending or recieving? Sorry I ask so many q's I am in over my head!

Comment: It's not necessarily a "directory" issue as much as it is handling the requests properly, you could have a script call itself using curl if you wanted based on conditions, same rules would apply. You need to check originating ip of the request. Something like this: `if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`

Comment: Must be some kind of internal blocking going on, not sure what, because if I change the api link it links to to the identical api I have on another server, it works ok. Maybe it's not handling my reqeusts quite right!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php), those two variables are not available in CGI mode.

> The HTTP Authentication hooks in PHP are only available when it is running as an Apache module and is hence not available in the CGI version.

however, take a delve into the User Contributed Notes. There is a number of workarounds people claim to have had success with, e.g. [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#70864). Maybe worth checking out.

Comment: That one has half fixed the problem, Thank you. For some reason now it works accessing it from an external location, ie: from my localhost I can call the api and get a response. but from the server to the api in another dir it fails! strange! I will keep looking!

Answer (score 0):

if it's for automated usage, no need to use HTTP auth at all. just send a secret token as a credentials.

```
http://example.com/service.php?auth=A235BDA74456CC3
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apache web server blocks the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` environment variable for CGI apps by default, which is what PHP uses to populate `PHP_AUTH_USER`/`PASS`. This behaviour can be turned off by recompiling Apache with the [SECURITY_HOLE_PASS_AUTHORIZATION](http://httpd.apache.org/dev/apidoc/apidoc_SECURITY_HOLE_PASS_AUTHORIZATION.html) flag set.

The “security hole” is that any other users on a shared server will be able to see the passwords of users authenticating with your site. Whether that's *actually* a security hole for you depends; often not.

If you are on a cheapo shared server chances are you are not going to get the chance to recompile Apache.

> Do you know if it is possible to use a work around similar to here

Yes, it should do, if you have `mod_rewrite` available. (The caveats about it being potentially a “security hole” still apply.)

It is, however, ugly, and complicates deployment. Also there are a few problems with the example script given (the use of `explode` discards any `:` characters in the password, and the `echo`s without proper use of `htmlspecialchars()` introduce an XSS vulnerability.)

This kind of nonsense is one of the reasons HTTP Authentication is increasingly unpopular. Most sites deploy form/cookie-based auth instead. For an API you would typically have your own token-based auth instead of relying on Basic Authentication.

Comment: I can't recompile but I do have mod rewrite available. I have used this so far which seems to work:
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*) RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

If I can somehow get it to send requests to it's own API in a different dir I will be made up! :D Thanks for the detail of your answer. Makes a lot of sense now

Answer (score 0):

Check out

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1813

for a discussion of this and a detailed workaround.